# Set default value in State object in React Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

At the moment in my component I am setting the default value to 'null', but I am trying to default the active states value to the first object in the objects which is part of the state, a bit confused.

code so far:

```
import React from 'react';

interface ActiveObject {
    id: number;
    title: string;
    function(index: number): void;
};

interface ButtonGroupState {
    activeObject: ActiveObject | null;
    objects: ActiveObject[];
};

const ButtonGroup: React.FunctionComponent = () => {

    const [active, setActive] = React.useState<ButtonGroupState>({
        activeObject: null,
        objects: [{
            id: 1,
            title: '1 Week',
            function(index: number) {
                setActive({ ...active, activeObject: active.objects[index] })
            }

        }, {
            id: 2,
            title: '1 Month',
            function(index: number) {
                setActive({ ...active, activeObject: active.objects[index] })

            }
        }, {
            id: 3,
            title: '3 Months',
            function(index: number) {
                setActive({ ...active, activeObject: active.objects[index] })

            }
        }]
    })

    const toggleActiveStyles = (index: number) => {
        if (active.objects[index] === active.activeObject) {
            return "btn-active"
        } else {
            return " btn-plain"
        }
    }

    return (
        <> <div className="wrapper">
            {active.objects.map((inner, index) => 
                <button type="button" className={toggleActiveStyles(index)} onClick={() => inner.function(index)} key={inner.id}>{inner.title}</button>
            )}
        </div>
        </>

    )
}

export default ButtonGroup;
```

Comment: what is your problem?

Comment: At the moment the active state defaults to null, how would I default the active state to the first item/object?

Comment: First item/object? What first item or object are you referring to? Why can you just specify whatever it is you need to reference as the active value?

Comment: In the state there are objects with id, title etc

Comment: activeObject: objects[0] 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you move objects into a variable and set it's first element to activeObject

```
import React from 'react';

interface ActiveObject {
    id: number;
    title: string;
    function(index: number): void;
};

interface ButtonGroupState {
    activeObject: ActiveObject | null;
    objects: ActiveObject[];
};

const ButtonGroup: React.FunctionComponent = () => {
    const objectsArray = [{
            id: 1,
            title: '1 Week',
            function(index: number) {
                setActive({ ...active, activeObject: active.objects[index] })
            }

        }, {
            id: 2,
            title: '1 Month',
            function(index: number) {
                setActive({ ...active, activeObject: active.objects[index] })

            }
        }, {
            id: 3,
            title: '3 Months',
            function(index: number) {
                setActive({ ...active, activeObject: active.objects[index] })

            }
        }];

    const [active, setActive] = React.useState<ButtonGroupState>({
        activeObject: objectsArray[0],
        objects: objectsArray
    })

    const toggleActiveStyles = (index: number) => {
        if (active.objects[index] === active.activeObject) {
            return "bp-active"
        } else {
            return " btn-plain"
        }
    }

    return (
        <> <div className="wrapper">
            {active.objects.map((inner, index) => 
                <button type="button" className={toggleActiveStyles(index)} onClick={() => inner.function(index)} key={inner.id}>{inner.title}</button>
            )}
        </div>
        </>

    )
}

export default ButtonGroup;
```

Comment: That actually makes more sense, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can either duplicate the first element data as the initial state. *Note: factoring the array definition out would be an optimization*.

```
const ButtonGroup: React.FunctionComponent = () => {
  const [active, setActive] = React.useState<ButtonGroupState>({
    activeObject: {
      id: 1,
      title: '1 Week',
      function(index: number) {
        setActive({ ...active, activeObject: active.objects[index] })
      }
    },
    objects: [{
      id: 1,
      title: '1 Week',
      function(index: number) {
        setActive({ ...active, activeObject: active.objects[index] })
      }
    }, {
      id: 2,
      title: '1 Month',
      function(index: number) {
        setActive({ ...active, activeObject: active.objects[index] })

      }
    }, {
      id: 3,
      title: '3 Months',
      function(index: number) {
        setActive({ ...active, activeObject: active.objects[index] })
      }
    }]
  });
```

or use an `useEffect` hook to set it on the initial render.

```
React.useEffect(() => {
  setActive(active[0]);
}, []);
```

### Note

You appear to have a logical bug with the functions where they will have stale enclosures the `active` and `activeObject` state. This may be ok for the `active.object` if it's never updated. Since it's the same function for each element you should factor this out so your code is more DRY, and use a functional update.

You likely also don't what to duplicate state. Just store the active id (or index) and reference this in your code when accessing/passing props.

```
const setActive = (index: number) => {
  setActive(active => ({
    ...active,
    activeObject: index,
  }));
}
```

Then use/pass `setActive` as a prop where you need to.

```
...
activeObject={active.objects[active.activeObject]}
setActive={setActive}
...
```

Comment: Thanks that is a way I was thinking, but I think I over thought on it, so got confused.